# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error Config not found error IIS 7

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, .net, web.config

I am trying to deploy a .net core 3.0 MVC application to a web server via IIS 7 and I am getting the following server error:

**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**

Config Source:
   -1: 
    0:

This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.

**This is what I have done so far:**

1- Via Visual Studio 2019 I publish my app to a folder directory.

2- Add folder to my servers c drive in correct folder

3- In IIS set up a new application pool

4- Add a new site on port 8070.

5- Check permissions and give all necessary permissions needed.

When I done this locally it worked fine but on the server it won't work at all.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYF1O.png)

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Comment: IIS can not read your web.config, you need to double check the NTFS permissions.